# Where can I search the web for sites that are hotlinking JavaScript from a particular domain?

Tags: google, yahoo, search-engine, bing

Similar to Google's inanchor: operator, I'm looking for a search engine that will let me search for sites that are using a particular JavaScript.

For instance I would like to search to compare the results for

> "usingscript:http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" 
>   vs
>
> "usingscript:http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blekko's "webgrep" feature does exactly this.

https://blekko.com/webgrep

Another alternative is to use CommonCrawl's dataset, which costs ~ $70 in AWS time to grep through once.